# Netty Zero-copy in windows

Tags: java, client-server, netty, zero-copy

1)Is Netty's zero-copy work on windows 7?

2)Does anyone have examples of Netty's zero-copy usage for client-server?

3) I have also found an example of zero-copy using FileChannel, what's the defference between netty realization and java.nio.channels.FileChannel realization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `DefaultFileRegion` and it should work on Linux/MacOS/Windows. This makes internally use of `FileChannel.`.

Something like:

```
FileRegion region = new DefaultFileRegion(...);
channel.writeAndFlush(region);
```

Comment: can i use netty zero-copy with ssl?